# Comparing dataframe rows that contain strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Consider this dataframe:

```
id     name           date_time                 strings   
1      'AAA'    2018-08-03 18:00:00             1125,1517,656,657
1      'AAA'    2018-08-03 18:45:00             128,131,646,535,157,159
1      'AAA'    2018-08-03 18:49:00             131
1      'BBB'    2018-08-03 19:41:00             0
1      'BBB'    2018-08-05 19:30:00             0
1      'AAA'    2018-08-04 11:00:00             131
1      'AAA'    2018-08-04 11:30:00             1000
1      'AAA'    2018-08-04 11:33:00             1000,5555
```

Firstly, I want to check group of rows that share id and name if there is a common string between each consecutive rows then match is True(some of strings column have no value so they have been filled by 0. The desired output:

```
id     name           date_time                 strings                    match       
1      'AAA'    2018-08-03 18:00:00             1125,128,1517,656,657       False       
1      'AAA'    2018-08-03 18:45:00             128,131,646,535,157,159     True       
1      'AAA'    2018-08-03 18:49:00             131                         True
1      'BBB'    2018-08-03 19:41:00             0                           False
1      'BBB'    2018-08-05 19:30:00             0                           False
1      'AAA'    2018-08-04 11:00:00             131                         True
1      'AAA'    2018-08-04 11:30:00             1000                        False
1      'AAA'    2018-08-04 11:33:00             1000,5555                   True
```

Then group rows by id and name and find the time difference between each consecutive rows in which match values are True if the time difference is less than 00:05:00 the flag is 1.The final output:

```
id     name           date_time                 strings                    diff        flag      
1      'AAA'    2018-08-03 18:00:00             1125,128,1517,656,657       00:00:00    0  
1      'AAA'    2018-08-03 18:45:00             128,131,646,535,157,159     00:00:00    0      
1      'AAA'    2018-08-03 18:49:00             131                         00:04:00    1
1      'BBB'    2018-08-03 19:41:00             0                           00:00:00    0
1      'BBB'    2018-08-05 19:30:00             0                           00:00:00    0
1      'AAA'    2018-08-04 11:00:00             131                         16:15:00    0
1      'AAA'    2018-08-04 11:30:00             1000                        00:00:00    0
1      'AAA'    2018-08-04 11:33:00             1000,5555                   00:33:00    0
```

For the first part I've tried this code but it doesn't work correctly:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['id','name'])
z = []
for index,row in grouped:
    z.append(list(zip(row['strings'], row['strings'].shift())))
df['match'] = [bool(set(str(s1).split(','))& set(str(s2).split(','))) for i in range(len(z)) for s1,s2 in z[i]]
```

For the second part I've tried different solutions no one of them is working.

any hints are appreciated.

Comment: should the six row of match be True?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to compare cad sharpens with the previous one use:

```
dummies=df.strings.str.get_dummies(',')
c1=df['strings'].ne('0')
c2=( dummies.groupby([df['id'],df['name']]).shift().eq(dummies) & dummies.ge(1) ).any(axis=1)
df['match']=c1&c2
df['diff']=( df.groupby(['id','name','match'])['date_time']
               .diff()
               .where(df['match'])
               .fillna(pd.Timedelta(hours=0)) )
print(df)

   id   name           date_time                  strings  match     diff
0   1  'AAA' 2018-08-03 18:00:00    1125,128,1517,656,657  False 00:00:00
1   1  'AAA' 2018-08-03 18:45:00  128,131,646,535,157,159   True 00:00:00
2   1  'AAA' 2018-08-03 18:49:00                      131   True 00:04:00
3   1  'BBB' 2018-08-03 19:41:00                        0  False 00:00:00
4   1  'BBB' 2018-08-05 19:30:00                        0  False 00:00:00
5   1  'AAA' 2018-08-04 11:00:00                      131   True 16:11:00
6   1  'AAA' 2018-08-04 11:30:00                     1000  False 00:00:00
7   1  'AAA' 2018-08-04 11:33:00                1000,5555   True 00:33:00
```

---

if you want to compare each row with the adjacent ones:

```
dummies=df.strings.str.get_dummies(',')
c1=df['strings'].ne('0') # or  df['strings'].ne(0)
c2=( (dummies.groupby([df['id'],df['name']],as_index=False)
             .rolling(3,center=True,min_periods=1)
             .sum()
             .gt(1) ).any(axis=1)
                     .reset_index(level=0,drop='level_0') )
df['match']=c1&c2
df['diff']=( df.groupby(['id','name','match'])['date_time']
               .diff()
               .where(df['match'])
               .fillna(pd.Timedelta(hours=0)) )
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   id   name           date_time                  strings  match     diff
0   1  'AAA' 2018-08-03 18:00:00        1125,1517,656,657  False 00:00:00
1   1  'AAA' 2018-08-03 18:45:00  128,131,646,535,157,159   True 00:00:00
2   1  'AAA' 2018-08-03 18:49:00                      131   True 00:04:00
3   1  'BBB' 2018-08-03 19:41:00                        0  False 00:00:00
4   1  'BBB' 2018-08-05 19:30:00                        0  False 00:00:00
5   1  'AAA' 2018-08-04 11:00:00                      131   True 16:11:00
6   1  'AAA' 2018-08-04 11:30:00                     1000   True 00:30:00
7   1  'AAA' 2018-08-04 11:33:00                1000,5555   True 00:03:00
```

Comment: Thank you. The six row of match should be False as 1000 does not match 131.

Comment: But match with the last row

Comment: I have updated my solution, please consider accept or upvoe